Can you automatically replace composite Keras layers with the individual ops?
I want to convert this composite model with this hierarchy into the individual Keras ops so that it can be converted to another format.
KWSTransformer(tf.keras.Model)
  ConvolutionBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer)

https://github.com/ARM-software/keyword-transformer/blob/master/kws_streaming/models/transformer_utils.py
Is that possible to do automatically? You can get the nodes and connectivity of KWSTransformer using KWSTransformer.layers[n].outbound_nodes. But only for non-composite layers. There seems to be no way to get the underlying nodes of ConvolutionBlock?
